# Get object from GSON in Android

Tags: android, json, gson

I have a situation here. May I know how to get json from "place" like in the example below through gson?

near.java:

```
public class near{
    private List<Place> place;
    private String type;

    public List<Place> getPlace(){
        return this.place;
    }
    public void setPlace(List<Place> place){
        this.place = place;
    }
    public String getType(){
        return this.type;
    }
    public void setType(String type){
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

place.java:

```
public class Place{
       private String name;

   public String getname(){
       return this.name;
   }
   public void setname(String name){
       this.name = name;
   }
}
```

I know that to get TYPE in the NEAR class, it is

```
Gson json=new Gson();
near resultType =json.fromJson(result , near.class);
```

May I know how to get NAME in the PLACE class? Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
resultType.getPlace().get(0).getname();
```

Comment: May i know what is get(0) stand for?

Comment: get(N) is a method of list that returns the element in the Nth place: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get(int)

Comment: May I know how to put PLACE class into setListAdapter or ArrayAdapter?